# How to stop a person from loading a function multiple times jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which works when the enter key is hit or when the submit button is pressed...I am using this...

```
    $('#searchBtn').click(function(){
    var str = $('#searchTxt').val();
    $.get(searchStr+"&text=" + str, function(data){
        fetchPhoto(data);
    }, "json");
});

$('#searchTxt').keydown(function(event){
    if (event.which == 13)
        var str = $('#searchTxt').val();
        $.get(searchStr+"&text=" + str, function(data){
        fetchPhoto(data);
    }, "json");
});
```

fetchPhoto is a pretty long process as it hits a few external libraries and if someone makes it go off multiple times it gives some strange results(multiple results)

How do I prevent this from happening? Sort of need a timer or a lock or something...

Comment: These are asynch methods. If you want to make them synchronous, try using the `.when()` and `.then()` wrapper methods.

Comment: Either look at `setTimeOut` or at `one()`.

Comment: There's the option of the global flag (Sergio's answer) or you can use .on() and .off() to handle your events.

Comment: i would recommend to add timeout to on keydown event in your case its good practice so you would not drive the server and client "crazy" like @bram wrote, also consider to disable the button with CSS ( u kill two birds with one stone u show the user some thing is happening and u dont need to worry for multipile clicks ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a flag to prevent the `.get()` being fired multiple times.

Try this:

```
var ok_to_click = true; // this var will prevent the $.get() to be fired when its value is false
$('#searchBtn').click(function () {
    var str = $('#searchTxt').val();
    if (ok_to_click) {
        $.get(searchStr + "&text=" + str, function (data) {
            fetchPhoto(data);
            ok_to_click = true;
        }, "json");
        ok_to_click = false;
    }

});

$('#searchTxt').keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.which == 13) var str = $('#searchTxt').val();
    if (ok_to_click) {
        $.get(searchStr + "&text=" + str, function (data) {
            fetchPhoto(data);
            ok_to_click = true;
        }, "json");
        ok_to_click = false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disable button until your process get finished and then enable it.